# How can I retrieve values stored in GCP's Secret Manager from a Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

You can register values in Secret Manager using the official documentation, and by executing the appropriate commands, you can retrieve those values.

```
//set value
firebase functions:secrets:set {SECRET_NAME}
//get value
firebase functions:secrets:access {SECRET_NAME}
```

Next, I want to execute cloud functions from a Flutter app and retrieve the value I registered in Secret Manager earlier. However, I'm getting an error and unable to retrieve the value. I've tried various things, but couldn't figure it out, so I'm asking for help here.  The function I tried (I've tried different approaches for now).

The following code deploys sample functions from "test1" to "test4" to retrieve values registered in Secret Manager under the name "SECRET_NAME" and make them accessible from the Flutter app.

functions （Node.js）

```
exports.test1 = functions.https.onCall(
  { secrets: ["SECRET_NAME"] },
  (req, res) => {
   return [process.env.SECRET_NAME]
  }
);

exports.test2 = functions.https.onCall(
  { secrets: ["SECRET_NAME"] },
  (req, res) => {
    res.send(process.env.SECRET_NAME)
  }
);

exports.test3 = functions.https.onCall(
  { secrets: ["SECRET_NAME"] },() => {
    return [process.env.SECRET_NAME]
  }
);
  exports.test4 = functions.https.onCall((req, res) => {
    return [process.env.SECRET_NAME]
  });`
```

Flutter side

```
`
void test1() async {
  try {
    var callable = FirebaseFunctions.instanceFor(region: 'us-central1')
        .httpsCallable("test1");
    var result = await callable();
    print(result.data);
  } on FirebaseFunctionsException catch (error) {
    print(error.code);
    print(error.details);
    print(error.message);
    print(error.stackTrace);
  }
}

void test2() async {
  try {
    var callable = FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable("test2");
    var result = await callable();
    print(result.data);
  } on FirebaseFunctionsException catch (error) {
    print(error.code);
    print(error.details);
    print(error.message);
    print(error.stackTrace);
  }
}

void test3() async {
  try {
    var callable = FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable("test3");
    var result = await callable();
    print(result.data);
  } on FirebaseFunctionsException catch (error) {
    print(error.code);
    print(error.details);
    print(error.message);
    print(error.stackTrace);
  }
}

void test4() async {
  try {
    var callable = FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable("test4");
    var result = await callable();
    print(result.data);
  } on FirebaseFunctionsException catch (error) {
    print(error.code);
    print(error.details);
    print(error.message);
    print(error.stackTrace);
  }
}`
```

The issue/error message that is occurring.

```
INTERNAL
```

("test4" is the only one without an error, but its content is null.)

I tried changing the function invocation in Flutter from using the function name to using the trigger URI, but the error remained the same.

```
`    var callable = FirebaseFunctions.instanceFor(region: 'us-central1')
        .httpsCallableFromUri("uri"); // triggerURI`
```

I tried specifying the region and modifying the permissions for the values set in Secret Manager, but it didn't make a difference.